# How do I open a new tab in PowerShell 6?

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell 6 on a Windows 10 machine, 64-bit. I can't figure out how to create new tabs for separate execution environments.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/how-to-create-a-powershell-tab-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6) from the Microsoft help docs says, "On the File menu, click New PowerShell Tab." But in my PowerShell, there is no menu bar at all.

And [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tabbed-console-starts-here/) says to click on the plus sign on the title bar, but again for me, there is no plus sign. The page also says you can hit Ctrl + Win + T to open a new tab, but when I try that, it simply puts `^T` on the console.

Can anyone help me figure out how I can enable the tabs feature?

Comment: the first link is for powershell-ise, not for powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top of the second link, you provided it says in big red text: "Sets and Tabs will NOT ship in the next mainstream release of Windows (codenamed RS5)"

And [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/6509358-windows-console-should-support-tabbed-pages) it says that the feature was pulled but remains a high priority

Answer (score 10):

You can use Windows Terminal. It supports Tabs. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701

[image]

**PS**

> And this page says to click on the plus sign on the title bar, but
> again for me, there is no plus sign. The page also says you can hit
> Ctrl + Win + T to open a new tab, but when I try that, it simply puts
> ^T on the console.

Probably you are referring to Windows Terminal. Use `Ctrl+Shift+T` to open a new Tab.

Comment: There's no key binding for new tab by default. You would have to add the binding to the settings file. See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings